# Puppeteer cannot goto web page to get selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer

**The problem has been resolved by adding cookie from an actual browser.**

I'm trying to get half-price products from this website https://shop.coles.com.au/a/richmond-south/specials/search/half-price-specials. The website is rendered by AngularJS so I'm trying to use puppeteer for data scraping.

- headless is false, just a blank page shows up
- headless is true, it throws an exception as the image [Error while running with headless browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RzZr.png)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function getProductNames(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 926 });
    await page.goto("https://shop.coles.com.au/a/richmond-south/specials/search/half-price-specials");
    await page.waitForSelector('.product-name')

    console.log("Begin to evaluate JS")
    var productNames = await page.evaluate(() => {
      var div = document.querySelectorAll('.product-name');
      console.log(div)
      var productnames = []
      // leave it blank for now
      return productnames
    })

    console.log(productNames)
    browser.close()
}

getProductNames();
```

P/S: While looking into this issue, I figure out the web page is actually **console.log** out the data of each page, but I can't trace the request. If you can show me how it could be great.

[The web page console log data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilIcb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding options parameter to page.to('url'[,options]) method

```
page.goto("https://shop.coles.com.au/a/richmond-south/specials/search/half-price-specials", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
```

It will consider navigation to be finished only when there are no more than 2 network connections for at least 500 ms.

You can refer documentation about parameters of options object here: [Goto Options parameter](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.0.4&show=api-pagegotourl-options)

Comment: I tried with headless false, empty webpage just pops up. With headless true, the same error as the screenshot above. Can you try that link on your end?

Comment: Thank you, the issue has been resolved by adding cookie from an actual browser.